# Append cleaned data to dictionary using if and loop technique

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset to clean and organize. Here is the link of the data set

https://github.com/irJERAD/Intro-to-Data-Science-in-Python/blob/master/MyNotebooks/university_towns.txt

So what I am trying to do is to clean this data set to the dictionary with the format {State: Town) for example {'Alabama': 'Auburn', Alabama: 'Florence'....'Wyoming': 'Laramie')

Here is my code:

```
import re

univ_towns = open('university_towns.txt',encoding='utf-8').readlines()

state_list = []
d={}

for name in univ_towns:
    if "[ed" in name:
        statename = re.sub('\[edit]\n$', '', name)
        state_list.append(statename)
        len_state = len(state_list)
    elif "(" in name:
        sep = ' ('
        townname = name.split(sep, 1)[0]
        if "," in townname:
            sep = ','
            townname = townname.split(sep, 1)[0]
        d[state_list[len_state-1]] = townname

d
```

However, the code of my output only gives the results with only the last town appended in the dictionary. I am sure there is something no right with the loop logic but I can't really figure out what is wrong. Here is the output of my code:

```
{'Alabama': 'Tuskegee',
 'Alaska': 'Fairbanks',
 'Arizona': 'Tucson',
 'Arkansas': 'Searcy',
 'California': 'Whittier',
 'Colorado': 'Pueblo',
 'Connecticut': 'Willimantic',
 'Delaware': 'Newark',
 'Florida': 'Tampa',
 'Georgia': 'Young Harris',
 'Hawaii': 'Manoa',
 'Idaho': 'Rexburg',
 'Illinois': 'Peoria',
 'Indiana': 'West Lafayette',
 'Iowa': 'Waverly',
 'Kansas': 'Pittsburg',
 'Kentucky': 'Wilmore',
 'Louisiana': 'Thibodaux',
 'Maine': 'Waterville',
 'Maryland': 'Westminster',
 'Massachusetts': 'Framingham',
 'Michigan': 'Ypsilanti',
 'Minnesota': 'Winona',
 'Mississippi': 'Starkville',
 'Missouri': 'Warrensburg',
 'Montana': 'Missoula',
 'Nebraska': 'Wayne',
 'Nevada': 'Reno',
 'New Hampshire': 'Rindge',
 'New Jersey': 'West Long Branch',
 'New Mexico': 'Silver City',
 'New York': 'West Point',
 'North Carolina': 'Winston-Salem',
 'North Dakota': 'Grand Forks',
 'Ohio': 'Wilberforce',
 'Oklahoma': 'Weatherford',
 'Oregon': 'Newberg',
 'Pennsylvania': 'Williamsport',
 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
 'South Carolina': 'Spartanburg',
 'South Dakota': 'Vermillion',
 'Tennessee': 'Sewanee',
 'Texas': 'Waco',
 'Utah': 'Ephraim',
 'Vermont': 'Northfield',
 'Virginia': 'Chesapeake',
 'Washington': 'University District',
 'West Virginia': 'West Liberty',
 'Wisconsin': 'Whitewater',
 'Wyoming': 'Laramie'}
```

Comment: You can accept the answer as what you have asked is been answered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for name in univ_towns:
    if "[ed" in name:
        statename = re.sub('\[edit]\n$', '', name)
        state_list.append(statename)
        len_state = len(state_list)
    elif "(" in name:
        sep = ' ('
        townname = name.split(sep, 1)[0]
        if "," in townname:
            sep = ','
            townname = townname.split(sep, 1)[0]
        d[state_list[len_state-1]].append(townname)
```

As you can see, the only major difference is at the end where you use `append` instead of `=`. The way you had it before will only return one city rather than all cities, which is what you seem to want, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: beside append, I think another critical thing you did is to use 'defaultdict(list)' instead of '{}' since append does not work with {}. Just curious, do you know why?

Comment: Right, "the only major difference" was of course not quite accurate. Defaultdict(list) is its own type of object that is *like* a dictionary but not quite one per se. Essentially, the way you create it is different than a regular dictionary, it's recognized by Python as a different type of object, and items can be added differently, but the resultant object behaves just like a regular dictionary. It's perfect for situations just like yours when you need to create a dictionary of lists.